# Does Hölder continuity in 0 and outside of 0 imply Hölder continuity overall?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f \colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ fulfills
$$
|f(x)| \le C |x|^\alpha \text{ for all $x \in [0, 1]$}
\quad \text{and} \quad
f \in C^\alpha((0, 1])
$$
for some $C > 0$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Here, $f \in C^\alpha((0, 1])$ means that $f \in C^\alpha([a, 1])$ for all $a \in (0, 1)$. (In particular, we do *not* require that there is $C' > 0$ with $|f(x) - f(y)| \le C' |x-y|$ for all $x, y \in (0, 1]$.)

**Question:** Does there then exists $\beta \in (0, 1)$ such that $f \in C^\beta([0, 1])$?

Obvious candidates for possible counterexamples are functions such as $f(x) = x^\frac12 \sin(x^{-1})$. If my calculations are correct, this function does not belong to $C^\frac12([0, 1])$ but still to $C^\beta([0, 1])$ for all $\beta \in (0, \frac12)$.